# Authenticated user post DJANGO, save form

Tags: django, forms

I am creating an app where user can search for recipes by ingredients. I want that logged in user can add recipe by himself. I have created form where i am using ModelForm. Now i want to do that after user push submit recipe will be added/saved to recipes which i can see in admin panel and also it will be possible to search for it, but now it looks like it is impossible to save the new recipe...

My code in view:

```
def add_recipe(request):

     if not request.user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect('login_required')

     add_recipe = RecipeForm(request.POST or None)
     if add_recipe.is_valid():
          print("your recipe has been added!")
          add_recipe.save()
     template = "drinks/add_recipe.html"
     return render(request, template, {'RecipeForm': add_recipe})
```

My form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from drinks.models import Recipe

class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['recipe_name', 'preparation', 'ingredients']
```

My templates add_recipe:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{RecipeForm}}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
</form>
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.drink_list, name='drink_list'),
    path('search/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
    path('no_name/', views.drink_list, name='drink_list'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('add_recipe/', views.add_recipe, name='add_recipe'),
    path('login_required/', views.login_required, name='login_required'),
]
```

Comment: What do you mean it is impossible? The updated object is not saved to database? Do you have any error?

Comment: Yes it is not saved. I think i must to write it different in my view.. something with save method i guess since I use modelForm. Sorry i am totally new and swimming in deep water ..:)

Comment: no worries we've all been there ;-) Have you had a look at my answer by chance? Do not hesitate to comment it so I can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your views (their names are not very explicit), but have you registered the view through your `urls.py` file?

Also, `action=""` in your template won't do anything. You need to specify the url to send your post request! `action` should not be equaled to "", but to the url you want to submit your form. In your case, you should have `action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}"`

Comment: I want that logged in user can create and save his own recipe... i do not know how to do it. Recipe should be visible in url /search. you can see i have added my urls if it is needed to get help

Comment: Check `<form method="post" action="">` in your template. `action` should not be equaled to `""`, but to the url you want to submit your form. In your case, you should have `action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}"`

Comment: I know, but i think i had everything wrong, because what i really want is that that the user can add recipe so actually save the form. http://lui93.pythonanywhere.com/ here is my website try to find "limon" so maybe you will know more what  i mean.. so i have updated my view upper but it is like puzzle not in whole picture yet at least i know pieces... :)

Comment: I did understand, but please read again what I've said. You want your user to submit a form, good. But if you do not tell **where** to submit the form, how do you want your client browser to know where to send the form? Also, I can not access to /add_recipe, which seems to be the heart of your question.

Comment: I have updated it now in git, you just need to register account and logg you in but it is not compliated and then http://lui93.pythonanywhere.com/add_recipe/ I see that form method="post" action, before i tried action = {% url 'search %} but it did not work

Comment: i made this change with <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}">

Comment: so what is the result?

Comment: it is working! thanks so much for your help. :))))))

Comment: Haha you're welcome! If you're happy with my answer, please do not hesitate to give it an upvote and set it as accepted so your question can be closed :-) Cheers

Comment: can you update this in main comment? Check <form method="post" action=""> in your template. action should not be equaled to "", but to the url you want to submit your form. In your case, you should have action="{% url 'add_recipe' %}"  ? :)

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks for suggesting this update!